# What has been initialized?

Tags: c, netbeans, gdb, ffmpeg

I'm learning the ffmpeg project

in one of the example program:

```
/* must be called before using avcodec lib */
avcodec_init();

/* register all the codecs */
avcodec_register_all();
```

I'm wondering what has been done internally with these two functions
I use gdb to see what global variables have been created, but don't find any variables

Actually my questions is not specific to the ffmpeg libraris
It's about using external C library
in those library there should be some variables created,how can i find those variables ?

I'm using Netbeans as IDE

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are external libraries, it is not always possible to see the variables at all. A good library won't have many globally accessible variables anyway. Most of them will be static or local, and then you can't access them, so they don't matter a lot, to you.

The documentation, if it is any good, should declare all variables, functions etc. that you can access and use. The header files are also a pretty good source of information, although they don't always tell how to use what you see. And, like in this case, if you can get the source code, that is also a good source of information, although it might take a long time before you start to see through, if the library is extensive.

**Addition**

If the library was compiled with debug info, and you have the sources, you may be able to see how it works and inspect all kinds of variables (local, static, global). The hiding of information from you is not primarily done to be secretive, it is done so you can't *access* the private information and (probably inadvertently) compromise the integrity of the private data it keeps. As I already said in a comment, that is called encapsulation and is, IMO, a Good Programming(tm) practice.

Comment: Thank you Rudy. So the external library can create a "black zone" in the computer that I can not acess but some other part of the library can? In my original post you can see that the function avcodec_init must be called before using avcodec lib. That's why I ask the question in the first place

Comment: Put in another way, if I were a library writer, I need variable a,b,c to be able to run the rest of my library functions.So i create init() and ask the user to call this first. then those variable a,b,c should be in memory ready for use right ? and this zone of memory the user has no access ? it is somehow protected ?

Comment: Yes, that is how you can put it.

Comment: Thank you again Rudy. It's weired that many books on C Programming doesn't mention this part. Could you point me some references on this memory usage or allocation or encapsulation issue in C programming ?

Comment: Ok I now realize that this is a topic relating to system programming, be it unix or windows. There's always a chapter on memory management in a system programming book.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you can get the source code and see it yourself?

http://ffmpeg.org/download.html